inequality in tangent space

It is well-known that in $\mathbb{R}^N$ the following vector
inequality holds : $$(|x|^{N-2}x-|y|^{N-2}y).(x-y)\geq2^{2-N}|x-y|^N$$ for
$N\geq2$ and $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^N$.

My question is whether the same holds true in case of a Riemannian $N$-manifold $(M,g)$. Suppose we want to verify for smooth functions $u,v:M\to\mathbb{R}$ the inequality $$\langle|\nabla_gu|^{N-2}\nabla_gu-|\nabla_gv|^{N-2}\nabla_gv,\nabla_gu-\nabla_gv\rangle\geq2^{2-N}|\nabla_gu-\nabla_gv|^N$$ for $N\geq2$ and $\nabla_g$ is the Riemannian gradient, $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ being the inner product induced by $g$. We can think $\nabla_gu\in T_pM$ for some $p\in M$ as a vector field $$\nabla_gu=(g^{1j}\partial_ju,\dots,g^{Nj}\partial_ju)$$ in local coordinates $\{x^i\}_{i=1}^N$, where $\displaystyle\partial_j\equiv\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}$. Since $T_pM\cong\mathbb{R}^N$, we can hope the inequality holds true in case of $M$.
Is the argument correct? Any help is appreciated.

Perhaps I'm overlooking something, but doesn't the usual proof in $\mathbb R^N$ work exactly the same with the euclidean inner product replaced by $g$? I can write it up later.
